# Unrelated cells changing random value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to process some data using Microsoft Excel 2010 and have come to something which confuses me. I have one cell which is doing the randbetween() function and is only referencing one other cell.

When I change the value for a completely enrelated cell to either of those cells then it changes the value for those cells which use the randbetween() function.

Why's it doing this and is there a way to stop it doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Volatile functions will recalculate automatically whenever an action takes place in Excel-e.g., entering data somewhere else, or forcing a recalculation of the worksheet by pressing F9.

Some of the volatile functions are

```
Rand()
RandBetween()
Now()
Today()
```

To stop volatile calculations from calculating, you will have to change the calculation mode to Manual.